# How GWT and PhoneGap works together?

Tags: gwt, cordova

I have been working with GWT projects, and the scenario with GWT is that it is compiled then deployed to a web server (like Tomcat), however I want to try out PhoneGap, so I can develop a Android / Iphone app using a single code base and perhaps using the familiar web-style UI.

If I use GWT with PhoneGap, would the application still need a back-end web server to display the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your specific question is no, you do not necessarily need the back end web server to display the UI.  That does not mean that your application will seamlessly work in phonegap though.  If you limit your GWT app to just client side code and call services outside of the GWT app you should be producing a web app that you can grab all of the content of the war minus the WEB-INF directory and drop it into phonegap (or the web server of your choice) and run the app without a java application server.  I have had very good success with running my applications on Apache HTTPD Server this way.  I have had limited success running it in PhoneGap though.  Some parts of the applications function fine, others do not.  So you will have to do quite a bit of testing to find out what works and what doesn't and then restrict your work accordingly but in principle it is possible to use GWT for developing a UI to use in PhoneGap.

Comment: what do you mean that it would not work seamlessly with phonegap?

Comment: All of the tests I did used GWT applications that were created as a standard web apps, not mobile ones. I'll freely admit they aren't necessarily the most well coded GWT apps in the world since we were learning on the fly. Most of our apps worked fine, but there were some features that did not. One example I can give is we had a status check on the activity start and based on that check we either hid or displayed a widget. The widget always displayed in PhoneGap even though the default state was to hide it. You may have quirks to research and adjust your app accordingly.